# python print array inside the dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to print 'array' inside the dictionary but my code gives me 'each value' of the array.

for example,
"array_ex" is a dictionary and has values like below with 12 rows for each array...

```
{"0_array": array([[17., 20., 15., ...,  42.,  52.,  32.],
       [24., 33., 19., ..., 100., 120., 90.],
       ...,
       [2.,  3.,  4., ..., 1., 3., 4.],
       [10., 11., 12., ..., 13., 16., 17.]]),
"1_array": array([[20., 20., 15., ...,  42.,  43.,  35.],
       [52., 33., 22., ..., 88., 86., 90.],
       ...,
       [10.,  11.,  17., ..., 71., 23., 24.],
       [34., 44., 28., ..., 42., 43., 17.]])}
```

and I want to get each row of the array as a result.

```
array([17., 20., 15., ...,  42.,  52.,  32.])
```

However, my code returns each value of the array.
How can I fix my code?

```
for i in array_ex:
    for j in range(13):  #cuz each key has 12 arrays
        for m in array_ex[i][j]:
            print(m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop over the rows:

```
for i,a in array_ex.items():  # or for a in array_ex.values()
    for row in a:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you never create any array so you dont get one. What you will want to do is something like this:

```
for i in array_ex:
    result[]
    for j in range(13):  #cuz each key has 12 arrays
        for m in array_ex[i][j]:
            result.append(m)
    print(result)
```